# Disable remote debugging in Appgyver

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools, hybrid-mobile-app, appgyver

I am using Appgyver to create a hybrid app and need to be able to disable the ability for the app to be debugged in the chrome remote debugging tools.

Any input on how to do this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, I found [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#configure-webview)

**Debugging WebViews**

On Android 4.4 (KitKat) or later, you can use DevTools to debug WebView content in native Android appstrong textlications.

**Configure WebViews for debugging**

WebView debugging must be enabled from within your application. To enable WebView debugging, call the static method setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled on the WebView class.

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
      WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
  }
```

This setting applies to all of the application's WebViews.

**Tip:** WebView debugging is not affected by the state of the debuggable flag in the application's manifest. If you want to enable WebView debugging only when debuggable is true, test the flag at runtime.

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    if (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags &= ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE))
    { WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true); }
  }
```

Comment: Where would this config go?

Comment: @SentraThis96 write it in your application code, try itWebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(**false**);

Comment: What provides the `WebView` class? I'm using Appgyver to write this Hybrid App

Comment: You should use `&` instead of `&=` in the `FLAG_DEBUGGABLE` check. `&=` modifies `flags` by removing any flags other than `FLAG_DEBUGGABLE`.